# unity3d trouble with ship floating on water

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

In unity, i have a ship [image: this is my ship]

And i have also water: [image: this is my water]

I want to make ship float on water, but(of course) what I get is this:[image: ship and water]
Is there any good way to keep water out of the ship? 
Just want to make that water inside ship not displayable.
Maybe there is already answer for my question over the internet, but I had no idea on what do I exactly type in google... and I had also no idea for title of this question, so please don't blame me for unclear title.

Not it looks like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

I don't use any physics here, the `y` coordinate of ship is constant.

To Doh09:
Your code seems to work, what i got is:[image]

But when I run game, what I got instead is:[image: black cube inside ship]

Comment: Can you give more info on how you get this result? Is it a problem of rigidbody offset ? a problem of colliders ? a problem of local origin of your ship 3d model ?

Comment: @Pierre Baret no, there can't be any problems with rigidbody, because I don't use rigidbody here. What info do you need? I only have there ship and water, that's all. I just want to make water inside the ship not displayable.

Comment: So how does the ship float? Does it have a fixed height (fixed y coordinate)?

Comment: @Pierre Baret yes

Comment: Then it is normal behavior. So if you want to keep it that way, you might explore solutions like shaders to compute intersection between your water and your boat but I don't know much about shader sorry. You can look for things like "remove intersection"

Comment: You'll need a stencil mask shader. They're complex beasts and while I have a general understanding of their construction, it takes more effort than I'm willing to put towards a project that is not my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=DepthMask

Using the code in the above link, I got the result you see in the images below.

[image: DepthMaskShader]

I use the 2 scripts below to achieve it.

The SetRenderQueue object sets the render priority during the Awake method. Lower numbers in the render queue means they are prioritized higher.

In the picture the boat has 2500, the depthmask 2700 and the water 3000. Although I might have only had to set the depthmasks, possibly the waters queue, but you can experiment a bit with that.

The shader itself (the bottom script) should be put on a material that your mask uses. You can then make the mask a child object of the boat so it always stays with it and keeps the water in the boat hidden.

SetRenderQueue.cs

```c#
using UnityEngine;

[AddComponentMenu("Rendering/SetRenderQueue")]
public class SetRenderQueue : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    protected int[] m_queues = new int[] { 3000 };

    protected void Awake()
    {
        Material[] materials = GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
        for (int i = 0; i < materials.Length && i < m_queues.Length; ++i)
        {
            materials[i].renderQueue = m_queues[i];
        }
    }
}
```

DepthMaskShader

```c#
Shader "Custom/DepthMaskShader" {

    SubShader{

        Tags{ "Queue" = "Geometry+10" }
        // Don't draw in the RGBA channels; just the depth buffer

        ColorMask 0
        ZWrite On

        // Do nothing specific in the pass:

        Pass{}
    }
}
```

For the sake of clarity, here is an image showing the hierarchy as well as the mask object without the shader.

[image: DepthMaskShader2]

Good luck with your game.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at this tomorrow (it's late in my timezone now)

Comment: Let me know if something appears unclear in how to implement it.

Also late here. Sleep well.

Comment: your code seems to work, but only in scene view. At runtime the mask becomes black. (see my question, I added images of it)

Comment: Try it where you have the water as a simple plane with a basic blue material on it using the Standard shader. Just to outrule that your waters material is somehow messing with it.

Also, what render queue level have you set the boat, depthmask object and water to respectively?

Do you still set the render queue level in the Awake method?

My test was during runtime, which worked.

Comment: In my case, everything is correct when  i remove the SetRenderQueue script.

Comment: Perhaps they were already in the correct render queue order. Glad it works for you now.