# holes with shader and setPixel Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, pixel

I am using clipping shader for cutting holes in my mesh. My shader is (it's part of shader):

```
        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {  
           fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            fixed3 normal = UnpackScaleNormal(tex2D(_Normal, IN.uv_MainTex), 1);
            clip(tex2D(_SliceGuide, IN.uv_SliceGuide).rgb-_SliceAmount);
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;//2//tex2D(_MainTex,IN.uv_MainTex).rgb;//c.rgb;

            o.Normal = normal;
        }
        ENDCG
```

My SliceAmount is a range. It works because it cut very beautiful hole in my texture. But I have problems with coordinates where to cut hole.

I am using SetPixel to make texture with black rectangle. So I use:

```
for (int y = (int)yStartCorner; y <= (int)yEndCorner; y++)
    {
        for (int x = (int)xStartCorner; x <= (int)xEndCorner; x++)
        {
            Debug.Log("X: " + x + ", y: " + y);
            texture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.black);
        }
    }
    texture.Apply();
```

Start and End corners I take from Raycast textureCoord. But when I try to convert float to int, my hole never is perfectly fitted, how you can see on image. Pink dots are points when raycast hit:
[image]

It's 3D, I used iso view to show, that my hole doesn't fit my raycast coords.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I don't know something important about textures? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could print the float and int values and I guess that you will see that the difference explains the offsets in the image.

Comment: Why do you need to cut holes in your mesh?

Comment: @Doh09 I need it in my project to make a procedural mesh with holes. I was thinking about making it changing mesh, but it's very complicated, because my mesh have to be properly textured. Imagine e.g. a wall with a mural and a window in it. It's something I need.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I was doing it and it gave me nothing. I think problem is that Raycast coord returns floats and setpixel takes integers, but I haven't idea how to avoid loosing data. And I'm not sure is it only problem - I am thinking about texture proportions or any Texture2D properties, maybe? Try to do it since couple days and I'm in dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: [unity3d trouble with ship floating on water](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753638/unity3d-trouble-with-ship-floating-on-water/48755638#48755638)

You might be able to use this solution.

It's made for making "holes" in the water for a boat, but surely it could be adapted to your case as well.

Comment: I try it at monday and write you back is it working! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I see you're using Depth Mask. I was trying to avoid it, but If I don't find other way to do that, I'll use Depth Mask. But could you write me how to work it with light and shadow? I need to "real" lighting through this hole and my shader gimme that. Don't know Depth Mask, too.

Comment: I haven't tested it further, but the shadow/light did seem to reach the bottom of the boat I was testing on in the water/boat example, so I expect it to work with shadows and light correctly as well.