# Unity 3D - Render hole in place of object B, which is placed onto object A

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, depth-buffer

I have a primary object which I'd like to make a hole of any shape in, depending on the overlaying gameobject's shape. I thought this could be done with stencil buffer tricks(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html), but as my project is for the HDRP, it doesn't seem to work.

Gameobject A has a shader and material set, so I don't want to change its shader as it's inherited.
Gameobject B, which is the overlaid shape, is free for any approach.
I would be happy if anyone knew what I should be reading up on in order to do this for the HD render pipeline (which makes certain shader code invalid).
Written shader, or made with the shader graph, any is fine.

Comment: maybe you can render gameobjectA later, using a second camera?

Comment: @zambari I thought about the render queue approach because I already have two cameras available, but won't I still need to flag the invisible pixels somehow? I don't know how I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this shader i used to create a "hole" in the water for a boat. Might be what you seek.

[unity3d trouble with ship floating on water](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753638/unity3d-trouble-with-ship-floating-on-water/48755638#48755638)

You could then use the intermediary object, as a zone for when the player (or anything else) should be able to drop through the area.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but no hole is generated. I'm thinking maybe it's because I am on the HDRP instead of the standard renderer..?
My object A is set to render queue 2500, and the hole(B) 2400, which also has the shader attached.

Comment: Ive experienced that some shaders dont work in the LW pipeline. Perhaps try make a test in a default unity project to see if thats the cause of it?

Comment: I was able to get it working in a standard project. The same setup doesn't in HDRP. But that shouldn't mean it is impossible in HDRP.. there must be a way :(

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt the shader to work on HDRP, or use a tool like shaderforge to make a new shader that does the same.

Comment: All examples of this technique that I found are either using stencil buffer or depth mask, something I can't seem to do anything about in HDRP based shaders.. and I can't think of why they made it like so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not finding a solution to this problem (for HDRP) so I will rephrase my question and ask again. Your advice works, however in the standard renderer. :) although my project won't be on the standard renderer.

Comment: At least it got your mind thinking that bit further :-)